# Будет ли ошибкой запятая в этом БСП?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, бсп

"С автором трудно не согласиться(,) события Великой Отечественной войны всё дальше уходят в прошлое..."

Answer (score 5):

Между частями бессоюзного сложного предложения при перечислении ставится запятая. Например: Был темный зимний вечер без снега, вагон гремел в сухом воздухе (Бунин).

Это не наш случай.

В данном случае вторая часть указывает основание или причину того, о чем говорится в первой части (возможна подстановка союзов так как, потому что).
Например: Я глядел в огонь и боялся поднять голову: казалось, кто-то смотрит на меня из темноты (Коваль)

С автором трудно не согласиться: (так как/ потому что) события Великой Отечественной войны всё дальше уходят в прошлое...

Или тире.

В БСП при обозначении пояснения, причины, обоснования допустимо употребление тире вместо двоеточия (особенно в художественной литературе и в публицистике):

Соседскую кошку мы не любили — она вечно сидела на нашем заборе и охотилась на доверчивых птиц.

Answer (score 2):

В заданном предложении я бы тоже не стала ставить запятую, а скорее поставила бы **тире или двоеточие**, хотя при выборе знака желательно видеть контекст.

Но вот объяснения меня совсем не устраивают, **неточности там такие**.

1. "Между частями бессоюзного сложного предложения **при перечислении** ставится **запятая**. Это не наш случай".

Перечисления здесь действительно нет, но запятая ставится не только при перечислении, но и при **распространении/присоединении** тоже, когда мысли по заданной теме излагаются последовательно. Такая запятая очень частотная, иначе бы наши тексты-рассуждения состояли бы из одних двоеточий и тире.

Для этого примера можно привести **контекст**, в котором **можно** поставить запятую, хотя перечисления там тоже нет, например:

*Писатель говорить о том, что мы уже многого не помним из военного времени. *И здесь с автором трудно не согласиться, события Великой Отечественной войны всё дальше уходят в прошлое.**

2. Сейчас очень распространено цитирование такой фразы: "В БСП при обозначении пояснения, причины, обоснования **допустимо употребление тире вместо двоеточия** (особенно в художественной литературе и в публицистике)".

Получается, что мы находим значение причины во втором предложении, собираемся поставить двоеточие по правилу, а потом говорим, что правило в современной литературе допускается нарушать. **И какая же здесь логика, зачем нам тогда правило?** Уж лучше сказать: автор, ставьте, что вам нравится, всё будет правильно.

Но всё это далеко не так. **Интонация** предложений при постановке тире и двоеточия разная, выбор знака зависит от контекста, от структуры предложения.

И современная литература тут ни при чем, у наших классиков в XIX веке **тире**, в том числе для обозначения причинно-следственных отношений, встречается часто.

С течением времени меняется синтаксис, поэтому расширилась сфера применения тире, но это вовсе не дань современной моде.